# connectby of PostgreSQL gives invalid return type error

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursive-query, table-functions

I'm trying to recreate the following `connect by` sql of Oracle's HR Schema in PostgreSQL.

```
select employee_id, manager_id, lpad(' ',level*2,' ')||first_name name, level from employees
start with manager_id = 100
connect by prior employee_id = manager_id;
```

In PostgreSQL, I'm using `connectby` of `tablefunc` extension like this

```
SELECT * FROM connectby('employees', 'employee_id', 'manager_id', '100', 0)
AS t(keyid int , parent_keyid int, level int);
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
ERROR: invalid return type
  Detail: SQL key field type integer does not match return key field type numeric(6,0).
```

Comment: AFAIK `start with ... connect by` is exclusively Oracle's feature. In PostgreSQL (and other DBMSes) you need [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to deal with recursive data structures like graphs or trees.

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks for the suggestion but I need the result using `connectby` provided by `tablefunc` extension.

Comment: So try `... AS t(keyid numeric(6,0), parent_keyid numeric(6,0), level int);`

Comment: @Abelisto I figured it out at the same time you gave me this answer.. Small Mistake. Please provide this as an answer so that i can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Why do you "need" to use the function? Using a [recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)  is much more flexible and complies with the SQL standard